# Can the interleaved digits of 2 algebraic irrational numbers produce an algebraic number?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irrational-numbers

For example take sqrt(2) and sqrt(3) .
sqrt(2)= 1.4142......    sqrt(3)=1.7320  now we interleave their digits , sqrt(2) takes odd digits and sqrt(3) takes even digits

so  we get 1.147134220 , does this produce an algebraic number , we know it is irrational .
We also know that sqrt(2) and sqrt(3) can be created from interleaved numbers .

I thought about trying to use a Fourier series or something, but I'm not sure where to start .

Comment: Good question, I would conjecture not but it seems like a very difficult thing to prove.

Comment: Seems hard to make much progress, maybe it's profitable to rewrite it in terms of a function and think about that, $$s\left(\sum_i a_i 10^i\right) = \sum_i a_i 10^{2i}$$. Then interleaving $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ becomes determining if $s(\sqrt{2})+\frac{s(\sqrt{3})}{10}$ is algebraic.

Comment: It is totally implausible that this should lead to an algebraic number.  I have no proof, of course, as it seems hopeless. I think you're posing the question in the wrong way. It is more natural to ask how to prove this interleaving result is not algebraic.

Comment: "we know it is irrational" - please work out why.

Comment: Dear commenters who say it is unlikely to be algebraic, and difficult or hopeless to be able to prove it: why do you have this intuition?

Comment: @cragar because the algebraic real numbers are a countable subset of the real numbers. So if a construction somehow produces algebraic numbers, that construction should have some arithmetic significance.

Comment: @SamuelCoskey because interleaving decimal expansions seems like an artificial thing to do. It seems unreasonable from experience to believe something like that should have any nonobvious properties, like preserving algebraicity.  I wonder how one has intuition that something like the OP's question might have a positive answer.

Comment: @KCd I get your point , but we do know that sqrt(2) can be created from interleaving digits just take the odd and even digits make them real numbers then interleave them , so then we could ask do some  transcendental  numbers interleaved produce algebraic numbers or do  some algebraic numbers interleaved produce other algebraic ,because we do know that they can created from the process ,   Might be easier to start with  simple numbers like sqrt(2) interleaved with  0.000000 , so we put a zero between the decimals of the sqrt(2) ,

Comment: @cragar that example with $\sqrt{2}$ is not persuasive since your input is two decimal expansions they have no importance on their own and the answer was set up to be a nice algebraic number. Having the input and output be algebraic, as in the OP’s example, is what makes that request unrealistic.

Comment: unrealistic its a real number , Im saying it is possible to build one from real numbers are you saying it is false that it can be created from real numbers ?

Comment: We know that interleaving digits interacts well with rationality...